# Android BroadCast receiver for vibrate and silent

Tags: android, android-intent

I need a broad cast receiver implementation where a user can check whether a phone is going from Ringer mode to silent or silent to vibrate and vice versa.

```
int volumeValue = (Integer)intent.getExtras().get("android.media.EXTRA_VOLUME_STREAM_VALUE");
```

I tried this code but it won't me help much because it gives same value from ringer to silent and silent to vibrate and vice versa. I actually want to catch the action when phone go from ringer mode to silent and silent to vibrate
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

Write this code in your onCreate() method of receiver:

```
 BroadcastReceiver receiver=new BroadcastReceiver(){
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
               //code...
          }
      };
      IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(
                      AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION);
      registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
```

Also add this to mainfest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.RingerModeStateChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: to handle phone mode, relay on: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#EXTRA_RINGER_MODE and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#EXTRA_RINGER_MODE, but why adding the receiver on the Manifest ? i think that its not needed.

Comment: @malik-Please accept the answer if found helpful after u got 15 reputation points!!

Comment: @malik M-You should always accept a correct answer as it could help others who has a similar problem and check this question !!!

Comment: Why is it required to both register the receiver in the manifest and in your code? I would think that one place would be enough?

Comment: it doesn´t work  AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION is not for VIBRATION!